# HttpClient not accepting Authorization headers (401 Unauthorized)?

Tags: c#, android, api, xamarin.forms

I am creating a Xamarin.Forms mobile app that targets Android with .NET Standard as my code sharing method. Unfortunately the API I'm consuming works in Postman but doesn't work in C# using HttpClient from System.Net.Http.

Postman request works using this header:

[image: Request Screenshot]

I have tried 3 different approaches but they all still return "401 unauthorized". I've also checked the INTERNET permission in my Android Manifest file.

```
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Token e2eeb1aa9f32eb0ekgn353b6fadb772");
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", "e2eeb1aa9f32eb0ekgn353b6fadb772");
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Token e2eeb1aa9f32eb0ekgn353b6fadb772");
```

Comment: Try to add a call to `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();` to make sure there aren't any other headers in there.

Comment: I have tried that as well to no avail.

Comment: Also, "Token" seems strange. Normally this is "Bearer"?

Comment: Yes normally it is Bearer but when I use Bearer it throws me an error. It only works (in Postman) by using Authorization: Token <Space> <Token Value> as the header.

Comment: Did the solution in my answer work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the header on the `HttpRequestMessage`:

```
request.Headers.Authorization = new 
    AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer","e2eeb1aa9f32eb0ekgn353b6fadb772");
```

Comment: This answer helped me today. I was setting authorization header on `client.DefaultRequestHeaders` level earlier which was not working.

Answer (score 10):

Please make sure your HTTP request **URL** is correct or not. Sometimes you may need a trailing **forwardslash** ( '/' ).
If you missed it in **HTTP client**, will not work but **POSTMAN** will .

Comment: yep, because of that missing backslash I waste 1 hour of researching the 401 error message..............

Comment: Postman also is lenient with http vs https - in my case, C# needed to be using https.

Comment: think there is a typo in answer. backslash is this one - ' \ '

Answer (score 0):

In my case, was fixed when I set the basic authentication in the AuthenticationHeaderValue.

```
var authToken = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_UserName + ":" + _Password);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization= new AunthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authToken));
```