# Building post HttpClient request in C# with Bearer Token

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm not really a C# expert and I have a post httpRequest in C# to develop and for this I created this method that takes a Uri, an object and a bearer token.

This method aims to build the calling request:

```
private HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
public async Task<UserResponse> CreateUser(Uri url, UserRequest userRequest, string token)
{
        
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");


    string requestObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userRequest);
    Console.WriteLine("My Object: " + requestObject);
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
    req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    req.Content = new StringContent(
        requestObject,
        Encoding.UTF8,
        "application/json"
    );

    Console.WriteLine(req.ToString());
    var response = await client.SendAsync(req); 
        
    string output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(output));

    UserResponse returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserResponse>(output);
    return returnValue;
}
```

My issue is that i'm not sure I'm passing correctly my header content. The return response is an error message telling I'm not authenticated.

Thanks

Comment: That looks fine. Does the bearer token need to be encoded in some way (e.g. base64)?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bryanbarnard/8102915

Comment: I don't think so .... I did try with Postman and I didn't have the issue.

Comment: If you've got a working example in Postman, then break out Fiddler, compare the requests sent by your C# code and by Postman, and figure out the difference

Comment: I found out the solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076479/httpclient-not-accepting-authorization-headers-401-unauthorized It seems that the end backslash was required ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you have to add token this way:

```
var baseAddress = "http://....";
var api = ".....";
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);

var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

var postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userRequest);
contentData = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl + api, contentData);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserResponse>(stringData);
}
else
{
}
```