# HttpClient 401 in production but not when running in ID

Tags: c#, http, dotnet-httpclient, webapi

Currently we have two webservers, one setup to provide API endpoints only. The other is like a traditional website. Let me refer to them as API server and Web server.

The endpoint were using in the API server is working as far as we can tell, it's showing results when we use a browser and enter the logon details. It works from postman, and it works when running the web server in the VS 2019 IDE.

It doesn't work when running in a docker container.

The web server application running to call to the API end point is using .NET Core 3.1, this is the application were having problems with.

The code itself is

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

and

```
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Settings.envApiBaseUrl);

                string URL = $"search?search-text=Amarajith";

                var byteArray
                    = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{Settings.envApiUsername}:{Settings.envApiPassword}");

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                    = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                        "Basic",
                        Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

                getRequestTask = client.GetStringAsync(URL);

                msg = await getRequestTask;
```

The problem we see is

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(Task`1 getTask) at Web.Controllers.WebApiTestController.TestEngineApiAsync() in /src/MatchmakingWeb/Controllers/WebApiTestController.cs:line 82 System.Net.Http
```

To be clear the API server seems to be working the Web Server running the above code to get a result from the API End point is not working.

I have looked on stackoverflow answers, and some other web resources. This one([HttpClient not accepting Authorization headers (401 Unauthorized)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076479/httpclient-not-accepting-authorization-headers-401-unauthorized)) seemed more relevant but I appear to be using that as part of the above solution already. Mostly I haven't been able to find what I need to help me yet.

I have confirmed the username and password are correct in the settings. I also in debug mode tried the URL which worked.

`ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("https://dummy-url");                        
                    });
            });
            services.AddDataProtection();
        }
```

`Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)`

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())   app.UseHsts();

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();       
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

The class which starts the website is

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // TODO sort out the DI for the DB

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseSetting("http_port", "1980");
                });
    }
```

Any help and pointers would be appreciated.
The WebAPI server has CORS enabled just in case thats a concern.

Both the Web Application and Web API applications are running in docker containers.

The docker compose segment for the web app is

```
    webfrontend:
        image: company/appname:latest
        ports:
            - 1980:80
            - 443:443 
        environment:
            - MongoDB_Connection_URL=mongodb://HIDDENURL
            - MongoDB_Database=MDBNAME
            - Matchmaking_SplitCharacterFreeTextSearch=,
            - Matchmaking_Engine_API_Username=USERNAME
            - Matchmaking_Engine_API_Password=PASSWORD
            - Matchmaking_Engine_API_BaseURL=https://ENDPOINTURL
        volumes:
            - .\keys:/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys
        depends_on:
            - mongodb
```

Comment: If auth is working in most environments but not in all, the most common reason is, that you have a configuration problem (username and/or password). If you do the api call from Postman to your docker api container. Does it work with the expected credentials?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen yes it works with postman and in the browser.

Comment: @404 yes I have output the settings in the log file for the docker container and it shows the correct values.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I also just added some more output in the logs to prove all the settings are being pulled in correctly from the environment variables.

Comment: If you are sure, the api is configured correctly, then we can assume, that the client is configured incorrectly. This may be: wrong credentials or simply the wrong host. Note that in docker compose, the host for your request is the service name of your api. CORS and HttpClient bugs will NOT be the issue here.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen thanks, some good pointers,  let me check.